# What did George Lucas think about Spaceballs?

Tags: george-lucas, spaceballs

Spaceballs is clearly a parody of the hit film Star Wars. Lone Starr, Barff, Vespa and Dot Matrix all closely mirror their counterparts; Han Solo, Chewie, C-3P0 and Leia.

[image]

George Lucas is famously protective of the rights to his films. So did he ever publicly state what he thought of Spaceballs and is there any truth to the rumour that he prevented a Spaceballs sequel?

Comment: +1 Good question considering how protective Lucas is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### What did George Lucas think of *Spaceballs*?

I don't know about publicly, but Mel Brooks has remarked in interviews that he worked with Lucas specifically to avoid those sorts of issues.

In a [2013 interview with *Maxim*](https://web.archive.org/web/20140223135520/http://www.maxim.com/comedians/interview-icon-mel-brooks), Brooks revealed that Lucas had given his blessing for Brooks to go forward with *Spaceballs*:

> **Did George Lucas give you his blessing on *Spaceballs*?**
>
> He certainly did, but he gave me one incredibly big restriction: no action figures. He said, “Yours are going to look like mine.” I said OK.

And in a [2012 interview with *A.V. Club*](http://www.avclub.com/article/mel-brooks-on-how-to-play-hitler-and-how-he-almost-89843), he claims that Lucas loved the film:

> He wrote me a lovely note saying me how much he loved the picture. He said it’s dangerous comedy. He said, “I was afraid I would bust something from laughing.” Which is a lovely note.

What's more, the same interview reveals that Brooks hired several of Lucas' companies (including [Skywalker Sound](http://www.skysound.com/projects/spaceballs/) and [Industrial Light & Magic](http://www.ew.com/article/2012/08/03/mel-brooks-looks-back-spaceballs)) to do post-production on the film, for the express purpose of keeping on Lucas' good side:

> I was very wise. You know what I did not to have any real trouble? I called Lucas and I said, “I want you guys up in San Francisco—at the ranch or whatever—to do all the post-production of the movie. And he said, “Oh, great, great.” So, there may have been five million bucks in post-production on that, and special effects, etc., that Lucas handled.

### Did George Lucas prevent a *Spaceballs* sequel?

It's hard to say, but it seems like the answer is no. According to all interviews, the limiting factor was Rick Moranis' involvement rather than any sabotage by Lucas. In a [2014 interview with *Parade* Magazine](http://parade.com/288348/scottneumyer/mel-brooks-talks-40-years-of-blazing-saddles-spaceballs-2-military-movies/), Brooks said that he isn't willing to do a sequel without Moranis, although considering the *way* he says it, it's hard to tell if he's joking:

> **Rick Moranis said, at one point, that *Spaceballs 2* almost happened. Do you think you can get Rick to come back and get *Spaceballs 2* to happen?**
>
> Without Rick, I wouldn't do it. I've got the helmet in storage, just waiting for him. *[Laughs]* It'll fit nobody else. Rick is five-five-and-a-half. It's a perfect fit for the big helmet.

Moranis commented on this in a [2013 interview with Heeb Magazine](http://heebmagazine.com/exclusive-rick-moranis-on-spaceballs-2-ghostbusters-3-and-my-mothers-brisket/45895), but didn't disclose the reason things fell through:

> **BA:** *Spaceballs II: The Search for More Money* was a conversation?
>
> **RM:** Mel wanted to do a sequel after it became a cult video hit. It wasn't a box office hit. It was a cult video hit, and MGM wanted to do a sequel. And my idea for it was *Spaceballs III: The Search for Spaceballs II*. And I was unable to make a deal with Mel. I couldn't make a deal.
>
> **BA:** In terms of just getting enough money?
>
> **RM:** I wasn't privy to what the budget was or anything, but the deal he presented me, what he wanted me to do, was not workable. It was two or three years later. He wanted me to … it’s better if I don’t get into the particulars of it. Because it is so specific, it’s counter-productive to talk about it. But I was unable to make a deal, and it would have been something I would have wanted to do. But that ship has sailed.

Comment: And now I hate Rick Moranis.

Comment: Mel Brooks needed most of the money, so Rick said *No deal, hoser.*

Comment: @MajorStackings - Take off, eh.

Comment: The good news is that Moranis seems to be talking about a sequel proposed a couple of years after the original movie.  I read somewhere, within the last year or so, that Mel Brooks is currently working on a script for the sequel, so maybe this time Moranis will be more willing to do it than he was back then.

Comment: @WadCheber Moranis is retired, and he said this concerning a possible return to Hollywood. "I’m comfortable with where I live...I’m not interested in doing anything I’ve done in the past … I have no idea. It’s not something I’ve given any thought to at all." http://moviepilot.com/posts/2015/02/07/whatever-happened-to-rick-moranis-honey-i-love-my-kids-2665024?lt_source=external,manual

Comment: Yes. He and Sigourney are reportedly enjoying their lives together in the Great White North.

Comment: @JackBNimble - If he retired about 10 years ago so he could raise his children, and if his kids are roughly the age I would imagine, they are probably old enough to be at college or living on their own by now.

Comment: You may also want to note that according to the same [AVClub interview](http://www.avclub.com/article/mel-brooks-on-how-to-play-hitler-and-how-he-almost-89843) that  Skywalker Sound and Lucasfilm actually did the post-production work on Spaceballs for a cost of around $5M

Comment: @Richard Added it in

Comment: @JackBNimble - I did some research.  Rick Moranis' wife died in 1991.  He retired from live action roles in 1997.  Even if their kids were born just before she died, the youngest one would be at least 24-25 now.

Comment: @WadCheber He also said he had no interest in doing anything he had already done. The implication there, he doesn't want to revive a former role.

Comment: @JackBNimble  On his Wikipedia page, he says he'd do Ghostbusters III if the script was good.

Comment: +1 Interesting answer. Rick Moranis wasn't that big of a star. Not sure why he wouldn't want another film especially one that could have been a big production under his belt.

Answer (score -3):

George Lucas must have been cool with Space Balls, he let them use the Millennium Falcon in the final space port scene! [image]

Comment: Er... So it would seem. This should really be a comment. Once you have [sufficient reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I doubt Mel Brooks would have even had to ask Lucas about using the *Millennium Falcon*, since parody is an exception to copyright rules.